# VS 2010 building unecessarily

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, dependencies

I'm building a DLL in C++ VS2010.

I've changed the value of the DEBUG TargetName by adding a "d", so that the definition of "TargetName" is now "$(ProjectName)d".

Everything builds just fine - all DEBUG build filenames have a postfixed "d" - this is so both debug & release files can live in one directory (this project is a tiny part of a HUGE set of projects).

However, when I press F7 with a DEBUG target, the project always builds. For example, lets say my project is called "MyProj". In RELEASE I'm generating "MyProj.dll" and all the other files (MyProj.lib/.exp/.pdb/...) - in DEBUG its "MyProjd.dll" etc. All these files look fine in their respective directories, but VS always builds in DEBUG on F7. In RELEASE, VS correctly determines that the project is up-to-date and does nothing.

So I enabled debug tracing in VS using `<system.diagnostics`> in devenv.exe.config to set CPS=4 and restarted VS. Using (sysinternals) DebugView I can see that the DEBUG rebuild is triggered because VS is checking for "MyProj.lib" & "MyProj.exp" rather than "MyProjd.lib" & "MyProjd.exp", i.e. its checking for the wrong files (which don't exist), so a build is always initiated.

Is this a known issue or is there some setting to get round this? Setting /IMPLIB does not help at all - this seems to be a problem in the "make" side of VS - the correct files are always built (if unnecessarily!) so this is an annoyance rather than a major issue...

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I've seen this behavior before as well.  I recall having to do a "clean", close out of VS, delete the pre-compiled headers and output folders, then rebuild everything.

Comment: Interesting - I cleaned the project and the problem has gone. Very strange. FWIW, I'm not using PCH at all. Still think this is a (tiny bit annoying) bug in the VS dependency checking...

Comment: My suspicion is that when you do a clean, VS clears out its dependency list. As I hadn't done a clean since adding the "d" to the TargetName, VS incorrectly was still looking for the old names (but only for the .lib & .exp files) rather than looking at the substitution of the $(TargetName) macro.

Doing a "clean" reset the dependencies so all is now well. I still think that this is a bug...

Comment: yeah, agreed.  when it happened to me, I was cursing VS until it finally annoyed me enough I had to do something about it...

Comment: @mark Please can you write that as an answer so the question can be tagged as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before as well. Not sure which is the required step, but I resolved by:

- build -> "clean solution"
- exit Visual Studio
- delete the pre-compiled headers and output folders (think I deleted the .sdf as well)
- rebuild everything